# Add loading page between HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mp4 animation, that i wanted to be played as a loading animation between two html pages. The video is about 5 seconds long, so i wanted this loading page to be the same lenght. Is there a way to do that?

If so, is it possible to choose for how long that loading page will be displayed, like 10 seconds, for example, so the loading animation would be repeating until the loading page is over?

Comment: i'm not sure what you exacly want, is this when you redirect between two pages or while  html page 2 is gathering data to show?

Comment: Its actually for when i redirect. Page 1 has a "next page" button that redirects the user to page 2. The idea would be for a third page to be displayed before page2 is displayed. Just like a loading page (But it isnt really loading anything. Its just so i can display the loading animation, for whatever number of seconds i choose).

Answer (score 0):

So for this I would add this to each page

```
<iframe id="loadingBar" src="loading.mp4"/>

<script>
   $(document).ready = () => {
       Window.setTimeout(5000); //wait for 5 seconds
       $("#loadingBar").attr("display","none");
       $(".page").click = () => {
          location.href = index.html?page=2;
       };
   };
</script>
```